# java object to json string to build jqmobile nested list

Tags: java, json, jquery-mobile, jquery-templates, nested-lists

Below is my object structure, I get the list of `OrganizationVO` from db. Could some one suggest how to convert this list to `JSON` format ?

```
class OrganizationVO {
    String name;
    int id;
    String mgrName;

    List<OrganizationVO> orgvo;
}
```

Below is the script and template code I am using to generate the nested list, I am able to see the nested hierarchy in the static form where the child nodes are displayed within the root node. Please suggest how to get the drill down effect of nested nodes and also use the data-filter option.

```
$(function () {
         $("#template").tmpl(clientData).appendTo("#target");
});


<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template">

<li data-theme="b" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-alt ui-btn-up-a"> 
<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-has-alt"> 
    <div class="ui-btn-text"> 
<a href="#${organizationID}" class="ui-link-inherit">
<h3>
    ${organizationName}</h3>
 </a>

    {{if organizationList}}
    <div>
        <ul> 
        {{each(i, child) organizationList}} 
            <li> 
            {{tmpl(child) "#template" }}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
     </ul>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    </div></div>
    </li> 
    </script>
```

Comment: I used GSON to convert java object to json string:

Gson gson = new Gson();

List<OrganizationVO> voList=getVOFromDB();

String json = gson.toJson(voList.get(0));
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: Once you have it in JSON format: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

Comment: Using the above scripts I am trying to display nested list with search filter. I am able to see the nested hierarchy in the static form where the child nodes are displayed within the root node. Please suggest how to get the drill down effect of nested nodes and also use the data-filter option.Could you pls suggest the ideal method to achieve the nested list effect? @PhillPafford

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code instead of in the comments

Comment: I have updated the question, could you please check what is my mistake ?@PhillPafford

Comment: Thank you for the [link] jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html had to understand deeply and work through some errors to finally get my page working..I still have long way go to finish this demo app :) could you let me know how I can give some points for your suggestion ? @PhillPafford

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the jQM docs on JSON and Creating Dynamic pages

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is Flexjson.  You'll have to ensure your object conforms to the java bean standard, but it's really easy to use:  http://flexjson.sourceforge.net Oh and its faster that GSON.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

It's relatively painless